# Aggregate individual metrics with collectd?

Tags: graphite, statsd, collectd

I'm working with an appliance which emits collectd stats (https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:Network) once every 10 seconds and doesn't currently expose any other collectd write plugins, but I have a graphite server that I have to get the stats into and a policy which says I can only send stats once per minute so graphite isn't doing the aggregation itself to ease the load.

I can't change the graphite server and have to handle aggregation prior to graphite.

I see that collectd has an aggregation module, and it's clear how this can be used to aggregate multiple metrics into one new metric (eg 'load' for a group of servers into a 'cluster-load' metric) but I can't tell if this can be used to aggregate individual metrics (eg one metric every 10 seconds into one averaged metric once per second). My hands-on tests have so far been unsuccessful. Is this possible, or should I just be using statsd?

References:

https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:Aggregation

https://collectd.org/documentation/manpages/collectd.conf.5.shtml#plugin_aggregation

https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:Network

Comment: As a note for those who follow in my footsteps, I worked around this by begrudgingly standing up a statsd or statsite instance on the host that was emitting collectd stats, but am unhappy with that approach because it requires statsd or statsite as an intermediate translator.